# Identify spoken language in the audio files

Tags: java, c++, python, c

I'm looking for an open source library to detect the language used in an audio file, such as a wav file. After some searches I found This http://sourceforge.net/projects/marf/files/Applications/%5Bg%5D%20LangIdentApp/ from MARF ( Modular Audio Recognition Framework).. Someone had already use it?

Comment: You maybe better try this at http://dsp.stackexchange.com..

Comment: Speaking as someone who looked into open-source voice recognition engines due to disability, well, you're mostly stuck. They never got past pretty primitive cruddiness.

Comment: This is an incredibly hard problem to solve, even for most humans. Can you explain why you want this?

Comment: In fact, let me explain my project. I propose a web service that makes the transcript of an audio signal. I have to initially detect the language spoken in the audio signal,in order to specify to Sphinx in which language the transcription must be performed. It's two separate parts: Detect language spoken il thé audio file and after transcript the audio signal with Sphinx

Comment: @ user1310305..
Can you please tell me.. which sphinx version(i.e. 3 or 4) did you used and how did you calculated the confidence score for language detection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [CMU Sphinx Open Source Toolkit For Speech Recognition](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) this project is quite active and in googles summer of code 2012.

Comment: but if I'm not mistaken, Sphinx will transcribe the signal and calculate a confidence measure on the text. What I want is to detect the language, without retranscrir the text file its

Comment: @user1310305 This seems to be the state of the art. My  only idea would be to process the audio file and check the detection rate of words in several languages and try a probabilistic estimation.

Comment: In fact, let me explain my project. I propose a web service that makes the transcript of an audio signal. I have to initially detect the language spoken in the audio signal,in order to specify to Sphinx in which language  the transcription must be performed. It's two separate parts: Detect language transcrir and after the audio signal with Sphinx.

Comment: @user1310305 You might want to get a paper like http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4518058&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D4518058 and go through related work.